# Valor inicial de useState a partir de un parámetro recibido desde un botón (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

Tengo un botón que envía un parámetro a una función "capturaCheck"

```
<ToggleButton onChange={(parametro) => capturaCheck(item.id, parametro)}>
  {item.id}
</ToggleButton>
```

En dicha funcion seteo el valor, previo el useState es el estado inicial en este caso 0:

```
export const UseCheckAtributos = (estadoInicial = 0) => {

  const [valueParametro, setValueParametro] = useState(estadoInicial); 

  const capturaCheck = (parametro) => {
   setValueParametro(parametro);
  }
}
```

Mi problema es que al pulsar el botón, el parámetro por defecto es 0 (obvio), sin embargo al pinchar por segunda vez le doy el valor del parámetro que recibo.

Mi pregunta es, **cómo puedo hacer para que el estadoInicial en vez de 0** sea el mismo parámetro que recibo?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás usando tu `UseCheckAtributos`? El valor del parámetro no es inicializado por el click del botón, si no por haber sido montado en el DOM. Luego puedes usar `setValueParametro` para cambiar el estado del componente por medio del `ToggleButton`. ¿Podrías explicar un poco que tratas e hacer? ¿Lo que quieres hacer es un componente que se inicialice en un valor determinado?

Comment: Pero en el evento onChange estas pasando dos parámetros, y en la función capturaCheck recibes uno... eso te funciona?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera en la función "item.id" es el valor y "parametro" es el nombre

Comment: @FranAcuna pretendo que me pase el parametro al primer click, pero me lo pasa al segundo click, porque el estado por defecto es el que prima, Necesito eso.

Comment: No entiendo dos cosas. La primera es que al momento de pasar en el onChange los parámetros hacia la función capturarCheck, estas entregando el id y el parámetro; mas, en la implementación de dicha función sólo recibes uno, que es parámetro, Ahora lo segundo, me estas diciendo que parámetro es el nombre y en tu state estás incluyendo por defecto un estado inicial que es numérico... ¿?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera eso es irrelevante, no tiene que ver con el tema, no he reproducido exactamente todo el código porque se sobreentiende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pretendo que me pase el parametro al primer click, pero me lo pasa al
> segundo click, porque el estado por defecto es el que prima, Necesito
> eso

Usar el hook `useState(estadoInicial);` **no tiene que ver con hacer click en el elemento**, esto ocurre cuando el elemento se monta en el `DOM`.

Te respondo con un ejemplo que creo que tiene la funcionalidad que buscas , esta basado en el código de tu respuesta... En este caso el botón es un componente de `React`, empieza inicializado con el parametro que pases en el prop `ini`. Uso tres instancias del mismo para que veas diferentes inicializaciones.

Si le das click al botón se le pasa el valor del `input` a la variable de estado `valueParametro` por medio del `setValueParametro` que nos da el hook `useState`, mira como el componente aparece **ya inicializado**, sin que tenga que ver con si se interactúa con el botón, luego puedes interactuar con el botón para cambiar el valor de `valueParametro`.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const testInput = document.getElementById("testing");
const UseCheckAtributos = (props) => {

  const [valueParametro, setValueParametro] = useState(props.ini); 

  const capturaCheck = () => {
   setValueParametro(testInput.value);
  }
  
  return(
  <button onClick={capturaCheck}>{`Mi valor es: ${valueParametro}`}</button>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <UseCheckAtributos ini="Empiezo en cero" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <UseCheckAtributos ini="0" />,
  document.getElementById("react2")
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <UseCheckAtributos ini="Me inicializaron" />,
  document.getElementById("react3")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h2>Cambia el valor y luego presiona el botón para asignarlo:</h2>
<input type="number" id="testing" value=0 ><br><br>
<div id="react"></div>
<div id="react2"></div>
<div id="react3"></div>
```